# Add images from Configurable Product to Associated product?

Tags: configurable-product, event-observer, product-images, associate-products

Essentially, when using the 'Quick Create' from the 'Associated Products' while making or editing a Configurable Product, no images are applied to the Simple Product that is made.

I'm using the M2E extension to list my items on eBay and it's required that I have an image for my simple products that were created as 'associated products' from the configurable parent.

Is there a way to use Observer / Event Handlers or rewrite some controllers to add whatever images from the configurable parent product to the associated simple child product?

There is an extension '
Automatically Copy Images for Configurable Product Variants' that says it does this, however, myself and others have installed it and never can get it to display in admin>configuration. I've contacted them, and others have to, never to here responses.

Using Magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we've updated the extension (1.5.0). This missing configuration file is now part of the installation package. It was tested successfully up to CE 1.9.2.1.

Thanks for your feedback.

If you have further questions concerning our extension please post them on the Magento Connect platform.

Comment: Is there any extension in M2 for this?